# Does the axiom schema of collection imply schematic dependent choice in ZFCU?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

This question was asked on math.stackexchange and didn't receive an answer. But I think it's interesting, and I at least would love to know the answer.

Let ${\sf ZFCU}$ be the axioms of ${\sf ZFC}$ modified to allow for urelements in the usual way. We do not assume that the urelements form a set.

The question is whether ${\sf ZFCU}$ plus the axiom schema of collection---i.e.:

(Collection) $\forall x\exists y \phi(x, y) \to \forall z\exists w\forall x\in z\exists y\in w \phi(x, y)$

implies schematic dependent choice---i.e.:

(SDC) $\forall x\exists y\phi(x, y) \to \forall z\exists f(f(0) = z \wedge \forall n\phi(f(n), f(n+1)))$

Comment: Can you add a link to the MSE version?

Comment: At least, a stronger principle fails: ZFCU + Collection does not prove the schematic version of $\mathrm{DC}_{\omega_1}$ (formulated as in https://mathoverflow.net/a/93331).

Comment: Does you assume foundation?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The MSE version seems to be [Does the axiom schema of collection imply schematic dependent choice in ZFCU?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4050222)

Comment: @FarmerS: U is the same as saying that atoms are Quine atoms, i.e. $x=\{x\}$. So you can't really rely on Foundation here.

Comment: Well, how about formulated as "For every non-empty set $x$ which contains no atoms, there is $y\in x$ such that $y\cap x\neq\emptyset$"?

Comment: @Farmer: I think you can assume that, yes. In principle, you can show that the universe is the union of $V(A^*)$ over all sets of atoms, $A^*$, where $V(X)$ is the von Neumann hierarchy starting from the transitive closure of $X$.

Comment: Foundation in ZFCU is Foundation in ZFC! In particular, ur elements are not Quine atoms, which are members of themselves. Ur elements = non-sets.

Comment: @Sam: Atoms can be seen as Quine atoms, and nothing changes. Yes, formally when defining them as atoms they are not. But it doesn't matter. That is why all those books about the axiom of choice essentially treat ZFU as either ZF without Foundation, or as ZF with a weakened Extensionality axiom.

Comment: @Asaf Of course. For various purposes, we can work with Quine atoms instead. I don’t think we disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Remark: Sam Roberts pointed out to me an error in the first version of the proof I posted earlier -- there was no reason that the desired automorphisms exist, as there was no specification of them on the atoms outside of the sets of atoms under consideration. The following is a significantly modified version, and I think this time it works. One should also compare with [Emil Jeřábek's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387424/does-the-axiom-schema-of-collection-imply-schematic-dependent-choice-in-zfcu#comment988246_387471) and [Sam Roberts'](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387424/does-the-axiom-schema-of-collection-imply-schematic-dependent-choice-in-zfcu#comment988238_387471) comments regarding DC$_{\omega_1}$ in the original question and below this answer.)

Assuming foundation is included (in the sense that for every non-empty set $x$ with no atomic elements, there is $y\in x$ such that $y\cap x=\emptyset$), SDC follows:

Write $U$ for the entire universe (of all sets and atoms).

If there is only a set $A$ of atoms, then $U=V(A)$, i.e. $U$ is the union of the cumulative hierarchy $\left<V_\beta(A)\right>_{\beta\in\mathrm{Ord}}$ above $V_0(A)=A$. In this case there's an easy argument by recursively collecting witnesses according to rank. That is, let $\beta_0$ be the least ordinal $\beta$ such that there is $y\in V_\beta(A)$ with $\varphi(z,y)$ (where $z$ was the given parameter). Then by collection, we can take $\beta_1$ least such that for all $x\in V_{\beta_0}(A)$ there is $y\in V_{\beta_1}(A)$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$. Etc, producing $\left<\beta_n\right>_{n<\omega}$. From this information we can build a set relation and apply DC to it to get the DC-branch $f$, i.e. such that $f(0)=z$ and $\varphi(f(n),f(n+1))$ for each $n<\omega$.

So suppose $A$ is a proper class. We will adapt the argument just mentioned.

Remark: I use parametrized collection in the proof, but this follows from the axioms in a routine way, by folding parameters into the ``$x$'' in unparametrized collection and modifying $\phi$ appropriately.

Lemma 1: For every set $x$, the transitive closure of $x$ exists.

Proof: Just the usual thing, taking the union of $\bigcup^nx$ over all $n<\omega$.

Given a set of atoms $a$ and ordinal $\beta$, let $V_\beta(a)$ be the cumulative hierarchy built above $V_0(a)=a$.

Lemma 2: For every set $x$, there is a set $a$ of atoms and ordinal $\beta$ with $x\in V_\beta(a)$.

Proof: Let $t$ be the transitive closure of $\{x\}$ and $a=t\cap A$. So it suffices to see $t\subseteq V(a)$. If not let $t'=t\backslash V(a)$, so $t'\neq\emptyset$ and $t'$ is not an atom, and note that $t'$ contains no atoms. By foundation there is (a set) $y\in t'$ such that $y\cap t'=\emptyset$. So since $y\subseteq t$, we have $y\subseteq V(a)$. But then by collection there is $\beta$ with $y\subseteq V_\beta(a)$, but then $y\in V_{\beta+1}(a)$, so $y\in V(a)$, a contradiction.

We now split into cases.

Case 1: For all cardinals $\kappa$ there is a set of atoms of cardinality $\kappa$.

Claim 1.1: Let $a,a'$ be sets of atoms of the same cardinality and $\pi:a\to a'$ a bijection, and $\pi^+:V(a)\to V(a')$ the resulting isomorphism. Then for all formulas $\varphi$ and all $x\in V(a)$, we have $\varphi(x)\Leftrightarrow\varphi(\pi^+(x))$ (with truth  of $\varphi$ evaluated in $U$).

Proof: By (meta-)induction on formula complexity. If $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_0$ then it is just absoluteness of $\Sigma_0$ between $V(a)$ and $U$ and since $\pi^+$ is an isomorphism (the language can include a predicate interpreted as $A$, which is equivalent to the sets $a/a'$ when interpreted over $V(a)/V(a')$). Suppose it holds for $\Sigma_n$ formulas, let $\varphi$ be $\Sigma_n$, let $x\in V(a)$, and suppose there is $y\in U$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$. Let $b$ be some set of atoms which is disjoint from $a$ and such that there is such a $y\in V(a\cup b)$. Let $b'$ be a set of atoms of the same cardinality as $b$, which is disjoint from $a'$. This exists by Case 1 hypothesis. Then $a'\cup b'$ has the same cardinality as $a\cup b$. Let $\sigma:a\cup b\to a'\cup b'$ be a bijection extending $\pi$ (which bijected $a$ with $a'$ already). Let $\sigma^+:V(a\cup b)\to V(a'\cup b')$ be the resulting isomorphism. Then $\pi^+\subseteq\sigma^+$, and by induction, since $\varphi(x,y)$ is true, so is $\varphi(\sigma^+(x),\sigma^+(y))$, which suffices, proving Claim 1.1.

Now suppose that for all $x$ there is $y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$, and let $z$ be given. Let $t_z$ be the transitive closure of $\{z\}$ and $a_z=A\cap t_z$. Let $(\kappa_0,\beta_0)$ be the lexicographically least pair $(\kappa,\beta)$ of ordinals such that for some set $a$ of atoms of cardinality $\kappa$, with $a$ disjoint from $a_z$, there is $y\in V_\beta(a_z\cup a)$ such that $\varphi(z,y)$.

Now suppose we have defined $(\kappa_0,\beta_0),\ldots,(\kappa_n,\beta_n)$.
Let $(\kappa_{n+1},\beta_{n+1})$ be the lex least pair $(\kappa,\beta)$ of ordinals such that for all sets $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ of atoms, if $a_z,a_0,\ldots,a_n$ are pairwise disjoint and each $a_i$ has cardinality $\kappa_i$, then there is a set $a'$ of atoms of cardinality $\kappa$ such that $a'$ is disjoint from $a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_n$, and  for all $x\in V_{\beta_n}(a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_n)$, there is $y\in V_{\beta}(a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_n\cup a')$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$.

(Note that we allow $\kappa_n=0$.)

(Such a pair $(\kappa,\beta)$ exists. For let $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ and $(a'_0,\ldots,a'_n)$ satisfy these conditions.
Using collection, there is a set $Y$ such that for all $x\in W=V_{\beta_n}(a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_n)$, there is $y\in Y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$. From $Y$ we can compute a $(\kappa,\beta)$ which works for $W$. But then the same $(\kappa,\beta)$ works for $W'=V_{\beta_n}(a_z\cup a'_0\cup\ldots\cup a'_n)$, by Claim 1.1 and since by case hypothesis, we can always find a disjoint set of atoms of a given cardinality.)

Now fix a sequence $\left<a_n\right>_{n<\omega}$ of pairwise disjoint sets of atoms, disjoint from $a_z$, with each $a_i$ of cardinality $\kappa_i$. (Exists by case hypothesis.) Note that there is $y\in V_{\beta_0}(a_z\cup a_0)$ such that $\varphi(z,y)$ and for each $n<\omega$, for each $x\in V_{\beta_n}(a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_n)$ there is $y\in V_{\beta_{n+1}}(a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_{n+1})$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$. So we have reduced the whole issue down to set-size, so applying choice, we get our DC-branch $f$, as desired.

Case 2: Otherwise. (There is some cardinal $\kappa$ such that there is no set of atoms of cardinality $\kappa$.)

Note that there are infinite sets of atoms, because for each $n<\omega$ there is a set of atoms of cardinality $n$, and applying collection. And given any set $a$ of atoms, there is an infinite set $b$ of atoms which is disjoint from $a$, for similar reasons and because $A$ is not a set.

Claim 2.1: There is a largest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there is a set of atoms of size $\kappa$.

Proof: Let $\kappa$ be the sup of all $\kappa'$ such that there is a set of atoms of size $\kappa'$. So $\kappa\geq\omega$. By collection, we can find  a set $Y$ which contains a set of atoms of size $\kappa'$, for each $\kappa'<\kappa$. Let $\kappa$ be the cardinality the set of atoms in the transitive closure of $Y$. Then $\kappa$ works.

Let $\kappa_0=$ this largest $\kappa$.

Subcase 2.1: For every set $c$ of atoms of cardinality $\kappa_0$, there is a set $b$ of atoms of cardinality $\kappa_0$ which is disjoint from $c$.

This subcase is just a simplification of the subcase below.

Subcase 2.2: Otherwise. (There is a set $c$ of atoms of cardinality $\kappa_0$ such that there is no set $b$ of atoms of cardinality $\kappa_0$ with $c\cap b=\emptyset$.)

Let $c$ be a set as in Subcase 2.2 hypothesis. Then define $\mu_c$ as the largest cardinality of a set of atoms $b$ which is disjoint from $c$. This largest cardinality exists like in the proof of Claim 2.1. Now let $\mu_0$ be the least value of $\mu_c$, ranging over all such $c$.
Let $c_0$ witness this choice. Note that $\mu_0\geq\omega$, since $A$ is not a set.

Claim 2.2: For every set $c$ of atoms disjoint from $c_0$, there is a set $b$ of atoms disjoint from $c\cup c_0$, such that $b$ has cardinality $\mu_0$.

Proof: If not, let $c'=c\cup c_0$ and observe that $\mu_{c'}<\mu_0$, a contradiction.

From here we can run a simple variant of the proof from Case 1, but starting with $c_0\cup a_z$ as our base set of atoms. That is:

Claim 2.3: Let $a,a'$ be sets of atoms of the same cardinality, which are disjoint from $c_0$. Let $\pi:a\to a'$ a bijection, and $\sigma:V(c_0\cup a)\to V(c_0\cup a')$ the resulting isomorphism. Then for all formulas $\varphi$ and all $x\in V(c_0\cup a)$, we have $\varphi(x)\Leftrightarrow\varphi(\sigma(x))$ (with truth evaluated in the entire universe).

Proof: This is now proved like its version in Case 1, but using Claims 2.2 and 2.3 (the properties of $c_0$ and $\mu_0$) to see that we can find appropriate disjoint sets of atoms (of cardinality at most $\mu_0$).

The rest of the proof is like before; given a sequence $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ of sets of atoms disjoint from $c_0\cup a_z$, they each have cardinality $\leq\mu_0$, and we can always find another set $a$ of atoms of cardinality $\mu_0$ disjoint from the rest. (So in fact, since $\mu_0\geq\omega$, one could just fix a sequence $\left<a_i\right>_{n<\omega}$ of sets $a_i$ of atoms, each of cardinality $\mu_0$, disjoint from $c_0\cup a_z$ and pairwise disjoint, and then argue that given an ordinal $\beta$, there is an ordinal $\beta'$ such that for every $x\in V_{\beta}(c_0\cup a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_n)$ there is $y\in V_{\beta'}(c_0\cup a_z\cup a_0\cup\ldots\cup a_n\cup a_{n+1})$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$. Then we can define a resulting sequence $\left<\beta_n\right>_{n<\omega}$, and apply DC to sets as before.)

Remark: Considering @SamRoberts' and @EmilJeřábekand's comments below, we might have $\kappa_0=\mu_0=\omega$, hence no $\omega_1$-sequence of atoms. In this case the proof wouldn't work to give DC$_{\omega_1}$, since it would rely on having a sequence $\left<a_\beta\right>_{\beta<\omega_1}$ of pairwise disjoint (presumably non-empty) sets of atoms. We got a sequence like this above because we had the set of cardinality $\mu_0$ of atoms to work with, and since (in the argument) $\mu_0\geq\omega$, we can actually partition it as desired. But if $\mu_0=\omega$, this clearly breaks when we want an $\omega_1$-sequence.

Comment: Thanks, Farmer! That’s a really nice proof. It also looks like we can use your observations to build a model where $DC_{\omega_1}$ fails, as Emil pointed out: namely, we take the sets with only countable many atoms in their transitive closure.

Comment: @SamRoberts Yes, that’s exactly the model I know of.

Comment: @SamRoberts pointed out to me a silly error in the proof (the claimed existence of automorphisms didn't make sense). I'm thinking about a modification...

Comment: @SamRoberts thanks very much for the tip. Hopefully this time it works. One can see where the proof wouldn't work if you tried for DC$_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: (Just to clarify, there is now a new version posted above, which I think works.)

Comment: @LSpice I was just referring to the comments on DC$_{\omega_1}$, not the error. I tried to clarify the reference. If you put such a link in, I'm interested to look to see how you do it...

Comment: I have edited in links to the comments, and deleted my original comment.  See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4763/is-linking-to-comments-possible and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358749/links-to-comments-when-the-title-has-been-edited.

Comment: Thanks, @LSpice